# Open in landscape an .xls file with 21 tabs of default portrait

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a server generated report in Excel .xls version, 21 tabs with data, portrait mode, `.5` left and right margins. I want to open the file in landscape mode with `.0` left and right margins using MS Excel 2013.

I have tried creating a Book.xltx file, but that only seems to work with a new file and not work when opening an existing file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't fully understand what you are asking.

However, be aware that you can click and select all 21 tabs and change the print settings (including margins and portrait/landscape) mode all at the same time.